# In Python, SelectPercentile.fit() returns unusual matrix and error,but Why?

Tags: python-2.7, feature-selection

I am a newbie in machine learning and I am building a text classification system. My texts are symptoms of diseases and Labels are name of diseases. I have  preprocessed all the texts and calculated the tf-idf values.As my training set and test set are a huge, so i am not mentioning the contents here.If anyone need, i can include that also later.Here are the labels_train, code and output tf-idf matrix of training set and test set:

labels_train = ['Heart Attack', 'Heart Failure', 'Asthma', 'High Blood Pressure', 'Dengue Fever', 'Lung Cancer']

Code:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile, f_classif

vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True,max_df=0.5,stop_words='english')
features_train_transformed = vectorizer.fit_transform(features_train).toarray()
print "features_train: ",features_train_transformed
features_test_transformed  = vectorizer.transform(features_test)
print "features_test: ",features_test_transformed
```

Output:

```
features_train:  [[ 0.          0.09420201  0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.06521722]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.185467    0.08837602
   0.06118382]
 [ 0.11319809  0.          0.11319809 ...,  0.          0.          0.07836844]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]]


    features_test:  [[ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
    0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
    0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.50792975  0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.16756124  0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.24203125  0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.19846908
   0.          0.          0.40979452  0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.19846908  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.19846908  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.24203125
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.19846908  0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.16756124
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.24203125  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.24203125  0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.19846908  0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.16756124  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.24203125  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.        ]]
```

The problem is, when i want to select features , i got a zero matrix.

Code:

```
selector = SelectPercentile(f_classif, percentile=5)
selector.fit(features_train_transformed, labels_train)
```

Output:

```
0 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.]
SelectPercentile(percentile=5,
         score_func=<function f_classif at 0x00000000053F6278>)
```

I can't understand why  i am getting this. How can i get rid of it or where is the possible bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the Solution

The only problem here is that there are only a few samples , which are not enough to figure out the ANOVA (Analysis of Variance) as  ANOVA cannot handle zero variance features. I should just increase the number of train data set. I've found it in details from these links:
https://www.quora.com/How-is-ANOVA-used-for-feature-selection

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/462